# How can i specify keytab file when connecting to postgres with golang pq using kerberos?

Tags: postgresql, go, kerberos

I am currently using golang pq library to connect to postgres database. I am successfully connecting using kerberos principal, but i can't figure out where can i specify keytab file to use to. In the source code it kinda happens magically, using some third-party library. It actually works, but i need to know for sure how does it know where my keytab is stored, so it can request initial ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Kerberos clients do not directly use a keytab; they expect the *initial ticket* to be already acquired and present in the environment. That is, you're expected to `kinit` before running the program, and afterwards the client's GSSAPI library looks for the `KRB5CCNAME` environment variable, which points at a file containing the ticket cache left by kinit.

(Normally with MIT Kerberos or Heimdal it could be many other things besides a file... but the 'pq' library uses a *very* minimal [pure-Go](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/auth/kerberos/krb_unix.go) Kerberos implementation which only accepts a traditional file-based ccache. So be careful if Krb5 on your distro was set up to use 'DIR' or 'KEYRING' or 'KCM' cache types, those aren't going to work here.)

If the initial ticket *isn't* present, the MIT Krb5 implementation will in fact automatically use a keytab to acquire the ticket if the `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` environment variable is pointing to one. Unfortunately, the 'pq' library doesn't use the system Kerberos library, so that won't work here either. (But it also wouldn't work if your OS was using Heimdal Kerberos; it's a MIT-specific extension.)

So the approach that will *always* work is to set KRB5CCNAME to a temporary path, then use either `kinit` or `k5start` to acquire a ticket from the keytab, before running your program. (The k5start tool will also keep automatically renewing or re-acquiring the ticket before it expires, without needing to use cron.)

---

Really, the whole `krb_unix.go` file is disappointing. If they can call the native SSPI on Windows, surely they could call the native GSSAPI on Linux...

Comment: Oh, it's bad. It causes a lot of problems, because initial tickets do not last forever and I have to watch for it's validity. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you maybe know, how can I generate an initial ticket using golang? It seems like gokrb5 is not capable of such things

Comment: Use k5start, its job literally is to watch for validity. (It accepts keytab files as input.) As for gokrb5, it certainly can, it's one of the first examples in https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/blob/master/v8/USAGE.md#kerberos-client

Comment: I actually tried to call ClientWithKeytab method, but it can't save granted initial ticket to file. Although it has Marshal method, but it casts it to ASN.1 protocol format, which doesn't work. Maybe there is a way to cast ASN.1 to krb tgt file format?

Comment: Well, krb5 caches _do_ store tickets in ASN.1 format – just with some additional headers indicating e.g. ticket count. I'm trying to find the MIT Krb5 page where the format was documented, but it wouldn't be difficult to reimplement it in Go, only annoying.

Comment: Found the docs: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/formats/ccache_file_format.html and of course gokrb5 has code for reading them, shouldn't be hard to adapt it to writing a ccache as well: https://github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5/blob/master/v8/credentials/ccache.go (...of course, it would be best if the pq library directly accepted some kind of gokrb5 credential object, without going through a file, but...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! We'll use that!